# Correct json format if struct doesn't have values?

Tags: json

This is a beginner question. What is the correct way is to include a blank structure, e.g. if I have this with full data :

```
{ "id": "1",
  "tree": {
          "treevalue1" :"2",
          "treevalue2" :"3"
         }
}
```

But then in another example the tree doesn't have any data at all, would this be the correct JSON representation of a blank tree:

```
{ "id": "2",
  "tree": {
         }
}
```

or would I have to do clean it away from the structure:

```
{ "id": "2"
}
```

And last question - would this be allowed in case of blank tree:

```
{ "id": "2",
  "tree": ""
}
```

Comment: You seem to be forgetting a `"` at the end of `"tree`.

Comment: yes corrected it, wrote it in hand - but you know the right representation ?